# Regex: How to make range to match minimum possible length?

Tags: regex, range, quantifiers

Regex: `[0-9]{6-8}([0-9]{4})`

Test Strings:

```
sfad 123456781234 afd sadfa fdads
sfd 12345671234 24312 fasdfa dsfafd
221 1234561234 safd safd23 34
```

Expected:

I need the end part `1234` captured in a group on each line.

Actual: No matches. :(

I would like to make `[0-9]{6-8}` to match the least possible characters so all these 3 strings would match. How do I make this lazy as it seems to be greedy now.

I need only regex solutions as this is part of a bigger solution. Here's a link to play with it: https://regex101.com/r/eF5pA9/1

Comment: You can use `[0-9]{6,8}([0-9]{4})`

Comment: Remember to add the `g` modifier if you want to get more than one match (if any): https://regex101.com/r/eF5pA9/2

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]{6,8}([0-9]{4})` with `g` modifier matches all three.

Thanks @anubhava and @Anderson Pimentel.